# Looking for an image tooltip jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, tooltip, callouts

I've been looking for a jQuery plugin that lets me have an image and mark certain areas on it where if you hover over it it'll show a tooltip with information about it. Let's say I have an image of a living room I'd like to be able to mark the sofa for example so when you hover it it'll show you information about the sofa. Do you guys know any?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the qTip2 jQuery plugin.  It is all you need: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#imagemap

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but hey, it came up in the SERPS for me so it must for someone else as well.  I just stumbled on http://ipicture.justmybit.com/.  I am a aTip2 user as well, but this one seems easier to use since its made specifically FOR that kinda thing.